# Defining spring security http element in two different files?

Tags: spring, spring-security

Is it possible to define the [`security:intercept-url`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-form-and-basic) elements and [`security:custom-filter`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-custom-filters) elements for a single [`security:http`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-minimal) in two different Spring configuration files?

This is so we can cleanly reuse the `security:custom-filter` definitions which will be common across many applications with intercept rules that will not.

---

I can't simply duplicate the `<security:http>` element because I get `BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Duplicate <http> element detected`.  I am well well aware of how to split a normal bean file with `import`

Comment: Hey, I know it's been a while but I have this exact question. Did you end up upgrading to Spring Security 3.1, and if so, did you find a way to implement the separation of interceptors and filters into different context config files?

Comment: @user14269686 Not yet, it's coming up.

Comment: Yeah, will let you know if I find out a way.. it looks like they had something else in mind for allowing multiple http elements [as per the docs.](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/security-filter-chain.html#filter-chains-with-ns)

Comment: I do believe that there is no way to split up an <http> definition into its individual parts. I ended up giving each application their own <http> and a custom config bean for defining the login page, index page, etc. The common component holds all the filters & security configurations, while each application sets it's own custom properties for it via the custom bean.

Answer (score 4):

As requested in comment:

Spring Security versions prior to 3.1.x do not allow multiple `http` element definitions.

3.1 does however.

[Here](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1171) is the Jira issue for the feature.

[This article](http://www.dzone.com/links/r/spring_security_31_enhanced_security_namespace_co.html) on 3.1 changes might also be helpful.

---

You can define another context file in your web.xml:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
      /WEB-INF/spring-contexts/context1.xml
      /WEB-INF/spring-contexts/context2.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

Or you can define a directory where your contexts would be and name them any way you like without having to specify each context file separately:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
      /WEB-INF/spring-contexts/*
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

---

Regarding Ayusman's answer, you actually can import your security contexts into your bean contexts:

```
<beans>

    <import resource="classpath*:/security-context-*.xml"/>

    <bean><!-- blah blah --></bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: Simeon How does this solve my problem?  I had no problem importing the file, but rather splitting the `http` element, which as I responded to @Ayusman, isn't allowed to be duplicated.

Comment: @C. Ross Ahh, http element duplication is not allowed in version prior to spring security 3.1.x, I assumed you're using 3.1. Which are you using ?

Comment: @C. Ross in 3.1 you should have no problem defining multiple `http` elements in as many files as you like, or in the same file. https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1171

Comment: 3.0.5.  So I can do that in 3.1 eh?  Might be worth upgrading, have to talk to the team.

Comment: Yes this is one of the major 'cool' features in 3.1 and the major reason we upgraded :)

Answer (score 0):

use the import in application context file..

```
custom-filter.appcontext.xml
.
.
<import resource="interceptor-url-file.xml"/>
```

Note that both files need to have the proper spring xml schema details and MUST be valid XML files.

Comment: So I just declare `security:http` twice?

Comment: @C.Ross I am sorry, I gave an incorrect answer. I checked the spring security xsd and it does not allow imports. May be some other member can provide a correct answer. Let me look around if I find something.

Comment: the security xsd doesn't, but beans does.  I'm trying to test now whether what you suggested works ...

Comment: Nope!  I get a `Configuration problem: Duplicate <http> element detected` exception.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on this error for 5 hours. Really stupid problem.

This error is a parse error that when you comment some lines  in applicationContext-security.xml, files are not generated correctly.

Let me explain on an example code.

```
<port-mappings>
        <port-mapping http="7001" https="7002" />
</port-mappings>

<!--    <port-mappings>
        <port-mapping http="7015" https="7515" />
    </port-mappings>
 -->
```

this lines are generated as,

```
<port-mappings>
        <port-mapping http="7001" https="7002" />
</port-mappings>

    <port-mappings>
        <port-mapping http="7015" https="7515" />
    </port-mappings>
 -->
```

so that,  compiler tells you "duplicate element detected". Because generated file includes duplicate elements.

I hope to help you .